# ASP.NET MVC 3 Design Architecture for Medium To Large Business

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I have been tasked with coming up with an architecture for a medium to large company that wants to switch to MVC for their application design. A brief rundown of their current architecture:

1. 90+ Web Applications created in Web Forms with an MVC type architecture, but not very functional. Basically a model stuffed full of anything you can think of and persisted to Session... Messy!
2. A Business Object Framework that started from CSLA.net, but has been modified so heavily you can't really call it that any longer. Lots of embedded SQL, no SOC, tied to Oracle, little messy, but it works.
3. They implement an "Application Manager", which is essentially another Model type layer on top of the Web Form application.

Anyways, I am looking for suggestions on using ASP.NET MVC 3 with their existing Business Object Framework, and I have come up with the following idea.

Implement a layer between their Business Object Framework and the ASP.NET MVC 3 Applications that serves View Models to and from the controllers. This layer would be where:

- Their existing Business Rules are validated and any errors are ported
  back to the Web Application.
- Data is retrieved from their Objects and
  turned into view models to give back to the controllers.
- Where controllers would hand back View Models to persist to the DB, maybe
  using AutoMapper to map them back to their Business Objects.

It would sort of be a service type layer??

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 90+ web applications? and this task has been given just solely to you? i would think this needs a roundtable discussion with technical/domain experts in your company, not really for SO.

Comment: @RPM1984 - LOL! I was thinking the same sort of thing, but most of the developers here are old Cobal/Main Frame programmers, with the exception of a few, who were ported over to ASP.NET Web Forms years ago, given a framework that was cooked up , and asked to go with it. There are a few who might get it, but for the most part, no. Anyways, I was looking for any recommendations to take with me to these design meetings. - Thanks!

Comment: its really difficult to answer this question. Basically, all we can gather is that the existing architecture is a mess, so by the sounds of it, your not going to be able to just *slot in* a service in front of the backend applications, your going to have to rethink all layers and (most likely) rewrite them all. :(

Answer (score 1):

Everything always changing, see my answer here for this question

[MVC Design and architecture advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127144/a-bit-lost-with-organizing-real-world-application-code-in-asp-net-mvc/8130811#8130811)